# LINQ: How to test if value is contained in set

Tags: c#, linq

This is probably a pretty simple LINQ question. I'm using LINQ to SQL and pulling a dataset.
My current code is this:

```
var tempTable = (from p in dc.Live_Diffs
                    where p.RowNum = 50
                    select new CustomResult
                    {
                        RowNum = p.RowNum,
                        ED1 = p.ED1,
                        ED2 = p.ED2,
                        ED3 = p.ED3,
                        ED4 = p.ED4,
                        ED5 = p.ED5,
                        ED6 = p.ED6,
                        ED7 = p.ED7,
                        ED8 = p.ED8
                    }).ToList();
```

How I can specify a where condition like the following: `"where p.RowNum is in the set: {50,60,70}"`.
I have a list or doubles, and I am hoping to avoid using a large number of `"OR"` conditions...

Thanks a lot - kcross

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
var listOfConditions = new List<int>{50,60,70};
var tempTable = (from p in dc.Live_Diffs
                             where listOfConditions.Contains(p.RowNum)
                             select new CustomResult
                             {   RowNum = p.RowNum ,
                                 ED1 = p.ED1,
                                 ED2 = p.ED2,
                                 ED3 = p.ED3,
                                 ED4 = p.ED4,
                                 ED5 = p.ED5,
                                 ED6 = p.ED6,
                                 ED7 = p.ED7,
                                 ED8 = p.ED8
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: That has to have been the fastest answer ever - thanks for that!

Comment: @keynesiancross: there were even faster ones, believe me :)

Comment: haha, nice.  You don't by any chance know to convert that List (created from that query) into once that would push "Ichanged" events for a WPF binding... would you..?

Comment: @keynesiancross: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

You create a list or array of the numbers you are looking for:

```
List<int> rowNums = new List<int> { 50, 60, 70, };
```

And then you check if it's in that list using a `Contains()`. Linq-Sql will turn this into an `IN` or a list of `OR`'s, I can't remember which.

```
var tempTable = 
    (from p in dc.Live_Diffs 
    where rowNums.Contains(p.RowNum)
    select ....
```